# The use of 'with' phrases in a conditional sense

Tags: meaning, prepositions

Is it possible for *with* PPs to have a conditional meaning? In other words, can *with* PPs function as conditional adjuncts? Consider, for instance, the below sentence.

> With your permission, I will leave.

The interpretation of this sentence (in the absence of any context to the contrary) is that if I receive your permission, I will leave. Would it be right, therefore, to analyse the *with* prepositional phrase as being a conditional adjunct? Do any other PPs have conditional meanings?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean, e.g.: "Considering x as a variable, it is clear that y must equal 10." (I.e., if we considered x as a variable.) Or: "By WNBA standards, she wouldn't be considered tall." (I.e., if we used WNBA standards.)

Comment: "If P, then Q". I think that's the most basic way of interpreting conditional adjuncts.

Comment: But you can go very broad with that. E.g., "On Mondays I work from home." -> If it is Monday, then I work from home.

Comment: Good point; I hadn't thought about that. Indeed, now that I think about it, there is a variety of words/expressions that can be used instead of *if* in conditional structures: supposing, assuming, provided (that), in case, so long as (or as long as), in the event (of/that), etc. Perhaps "If P, then Q" is too simplistic an interpretation. What say you?

Comment: I think that it's fine to define "conditional adjunct" broadly--that's what [H&P](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/grammar/adjuncts) do--but then the answer to your last question is simply yes, there are many.

Answer (score 1):

This conditional meaning ***with*** is listed in some dictionaries, such as [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/with), which is probably where you got your example:

> if given
>
> - ***With*** your permission, I'll leave.

Also, especially in combination with "right" or "correct" (but also other adjectives with positive connotations), ***with PPs*** can be interpreted as conditional adjuncts:

> Manchester United have not been so good playing on their home this season but I believe ***with the right formation***, they could win the match. ([ng.opera.news](https://ng.opera.news/ng/en/sports/383b8f9fa0162a46065df907e8698ee1))

> In fact, ***with correct instructions***, the vast majority of children are just as quick as adults in learning how to put in and take out contact lenses. ([VisionDirect](https://www.visiondirect.co.uk/blog/building-childrens-confidence-contact-lenses))

Another preposition that can allow for conditional interpretation is ***without***:

> ***Without training*** they can't do their jobs. ([CBC News](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/newfoundland-labrador/military-defends-absence-of-rescue-helicopters-1.946106))

You can add to this group of prepositions with possible conditional meaning, some synonyms of *[**with**](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/with.html)* (such as *accompanied by, alongside, coupled with* etc.) and *[**without**](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/without.html)* (such as *devoid of, deprived of, short of* etc.). I am sure there are others.

Comment: Are there any other dictionaries that record the conditional use of 'with'?

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/with) uses a similar example but expresses the meaning differently: _having received: 
with your permission, he'll go_.

Comment: Would you consider 'having received' to have a conditional meaning? The example Collins gives certainly suggests so, but I am not sure.

Comment: It probably depends on context and n the intention of each speaker. Of course, _With your permission..._ can be interpreted both temporally and conditionally. We are just looking at possibilities here, not at an actual situation.

Answer (score 0):

"With your permission" functions like an adverb referring to the verb "go": "I will ***go** with your permission*". Here it's at the start of the sentence (heading) because it's stressed.